# Аналог end = '\r' в input в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, print

В python, как известно у команды print() есть end = '\r'. Если она есть, то строка не начнётся с новой строки, а продолжится. Так вот.
Есть ли аналог такого же end = '\r'? То есть например:
    string = input(end = '\r')

Вообще, хочется чтобы он реагировал примерно так же, как и в print. Пример. Я напишу в коде к примеру:

```
string = input(end = '\r')

l = len(string)
print(string + " one two")
```

И введу:

```
...
```

И я хотел бы, чтобы в этом случае он бы мне вывел:

```
... one two
```

При этом чтобы выполнение кода выглядело не так:

```
...

... one two
```

А так:

```
... one two
```

Сразу скажу - я пытался такое написать. Но код говорит, что нет end у input. Есть ли аналог end для input в python?

Comment: Непонятно что требуется. Какое конкретно поведение вы от такого `end='\r'` ожидаете?

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Сейчас исправлю

Comment: Да и фраза «строка не начнётся с новой строки, а продолжится» тоже непонятна на самом деле. Символ возврата каретки ничего никуда не продолжает, он просто передвигает курсор в начало текущей строки. Как и зачем это должно делаться в инпуте, непонятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import sys

string = input()
sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
l = len(string)
print(string + " one two")
```